# Commas - yes or no? "Everwhere from..." list

Tags: commas, lists

Trying to figure out if this statement needs more (or less) commas:

> My position as a flight attendant has taken me everywhere from hiking
>   in Nepal, to swimming with dolphins in Jamaica, to eating pig brains
>   in China.

(Note: none of these things actually happened; this is only as an example. :)

That being said - do I need a comma:

- after "everywhere from"
- in between the activities? e.g., "hiking in Nepal to swimming with dolphins in Jamaica to eating pig brains in China."

Comment: maybe remove the middle "to" to make it flow smoother

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps an em dash after everywhere would do nicely here.

> An em dash, or long dash, is used:
>
> in pairs, to mark off information or ideas that are not essential to an understanding of the rest of the sentence:
> Thousands of children—like the girl in this photograph—have been left homeless.
>
> My son—where has he gone?—would like to meet you.
>
> to show other kinds of break in a sentence where a comma, semicolon, or colon would be traditionally used:
>
> One thing’s for sure—he doesn’t want to face the truth.

Comment: Use citations in answers, if you please.  In this answer your example would help readers.

Comment: Is it ok now? sorry about it.

Comment: yes. the community appreciates :)