# Does a "from...to" list require commas?

Tags: commas, lists

Take the following sentence:

"The success of the 1987 television show and 1990 film fueled the sales of everything from toys to toothbrushes to video games."

The following *feels* better:

"The success of the 1987 television show and 1990 film fueled the sales of everything from toys, to toothbrushes, to video games."

However, I'm not sure if this really qualifies as a list, or whether the serial comma serves any purpose. Is this simply a matter of style?

Comment: P.S. I found a similar question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/438485/commas-yes-or-no-everwhere-from-list), but the responses are unsatisfying.

Comment: Best without commas, at least here. It’s a style question.

Comment: I would be more likely to use commas when the items are longer.